# How to find of what vertices is made cycle in undirected graph if there is only one cycle in graph?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-algorithm

how to find of what vertices is made cycle in undirected graph if there is only one cycle in graph?

I have code for finding cycle in graph, but right now I need code that will find of what vertices cycle is made.

Here is code(in C++) for finding cycle:

```
bool dfs(int x)
{
    state[x] = 1;
    for(int j = 0; j < ls[x].size(); j++)
    {
        if(state[ls[x][j]] == 1 and parent[x] != ls[x][j])
        {
            t = 0; // Graph contains cycle.
            return t;
        }
        if(state[ls[x][j]] == 0)
        {
            parent[ls[x][j]] = x;
            dfs(ls[x][j]);
        }
    }
}

void detect_cycle()
{
    memset(state, 0, sizeof state);
    memset(parent, 0, sizeof parent);
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        if(state[i] == false)
            dfs(i);
}
```

Thanks.

Here is the final code. Thanks guys.

```
bool dfs(int x)
{
    state[x] = 1;
    for(int j = 0; j < ls[x].size(); j++)
    {
        if(state[ls[x][j]] == 1 and parent[x] != ls[x][j])
        {
            if(t)
            {
                printf("Cycle entry: %d\n", ls[x][j]);
                printf("Cycle contains: %d, %d ", ls[x][j], x);
                int cycleNode = parent[x];
                while(cycleNode != ls[x][j])
                {
                    printf("%d ", cycleNode);
                    cycleNode = parent[cycleNode];
                }
            }
            t = 0;
            return t;
        }
        if(state[ls[x][j]] == 0)
        {
            parent[ls[x][j]] = x;
            dfs(ls[x][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm right, then parent[] is an array (parent[i] is the number of the node that you vivted straight before you visited the i-th one).

Then you know that if the graph contains the cycle (you visit a node you have already visited), you know at least one node in the cycle (suppose its the k-th one). In this case, the parent[k] node also belongs to the cycle, and parent[parent[k]], and so on.

So, we get the next code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

vector <int> state;
vector <vector <int> > ls; //graph
vector <int> parent;
bool t = 1; 
int theNodeInTheCycle;

void dfs(int x)
{
    state[x] = 1;
    for(int j = 0; j < ls[x].size(); j++)
    {
            if(state[ls[x][j]] == 1 && parent[x] != ls[x][j])
            {
                    parent[ls[x][j]] = x;
                    theNodeInTheCycle = ls[x][j]; //ls[x][j] belongs to the cycle since state[ls[x][j]]==1
                    t = 0;
            }
            if(state[ls[x][j]] == 0)
            {
                    parent[ls[x][j]] = x;
                    dfs(ls[x][j]);
            }
    }
}

vector <int> GetCycle ()
{
    vector <int> cycle;
    int firstNodeInTheCycle = theNodeInTheCycle;
    do 
    {
            theNodeInTheCycle = parent[theNodeInTheCycle];
            cycle.push_back (theNodeInTheCycle);
    } while (theNodeInTheCycle != firstNodeInTheCycle);

    reverse (cycle.begin (), cycle.end ()); //to get them in the right order
    return cycle;
}

int main()
{
    int n; cin>>n; //the number of nodes (from 0 to n-1)
    int m; cin>>m; //the number of edges

    state.resize (n);
    ls.resize (n);
    parent.resize (n);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
            int a, b; cin>>a>>b;
            ls[a].push_back(b);
            ls[b].push_back(a);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i)
            if (state[i]==0)
                    dfs(i);

    if (t==0) 
    {
            vector <int> cycle = GetCycle ();
            for (int i = 0; i < cycle.size (); ++i)
                    cout<<cycle[i]<<" ";
            cout<<"\n";
    }
    else cout<<"No cycle\n";
}
```

Comment: Hey, tnx. I don't know why, but your code runs infinite loop. But here is my code. It's the same as yours. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. Ive rewritten it; now it should work and output the nodes in the cycle(in the order we've visited them).
Code: http://ideone.com/xlFo3U

Answer (score 6):

A naive method - just throw away any node with degree 1, until all nodes have degree 2. This is the cycle in the graph.

Comment: +1 Far more difficult to get wrong than using traversal, and just as fast.

Comment: +1 For an excellent idea. But how would you implement it to be running in `O(E)` ?

Comment: +1 Great idea and @banarun very simple if you define a graph using Adjacency List\Matrix

Comment: @banarun Using a list of the elements with degree 1, initially takes O(m) to find all of them (so you can build the counters for the degrees of nodes), assuming you have adjacency lists. I don't know how to do it with an adjacency matrix, those tend to blow up time complexity.

Comment: Here is the implementation for this logic : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-in-the-graph-using-degrees-of-nodes-of-graph/

Answer (score 0):

when you run dfs, if a vertex is marked when dfs() before, there must be a cycle.

```
     A
   /
  B
 |  \
 C  E
  \ /
   D
```

if there is only one cycle in graph, the vertex marked before is the entry of cycle, as B below, whatever the start vertex of dfs is.
and in your code,

```
if(state[ls[x][j]] == 1 and parent[x] != ls[x][j])
{
    t = 0; // Graph contains cycle.
    return t;
}
```

in the first `if() {}`,parent and t is unnecessary,change to:

```
if(state[ls[x][j]] == 1 and parent[x] != ls[x][j])
{
    cout<<"cycle's entry:"<<j<<endl;
     // Graph contains cycle.
    return false;
}
```

besides,your code need a `return true;` outside the `for` of `dfs()`.